# Parent's inset Box-Shadow overlapped by child element

Tags: html, css

I have this code

http://jsfiddle.net/4fz5g/2/

```
<div class='A' id='AA'>    
     <div class='listContainer'>
          This div is cutting Parents inset box-shadow
     </div>
</div>
```

My question is why does the inset box shadow of parent do not overlap the children? Is there a way to make it overlap.

p.s: I do not want to add inset drop shadow to children instead to make it appear as if drop shadow of parent is "casting shadow" over its children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to play with z-index to set the order / visibility of the elements.

The problem is that in the A element, you have also a background. If you set the z-index of the child negative, it will be hidden by the background.

One posibility to solve that  would be to create a pseudo element, and set the shadow on it:

```
.A {
    width: 80%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #408800;
    padding: 0px;
}

.A:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 12px;
    box-shadow: -12px 0 10px -10px #000000 inset;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4fz5g/4/)

Comment: Thanks. You are close but this solution prevented me from clicking any links on listContainer as A:after is overlapping the whole div. No events can be fired from listContainer as it is totally shielded.

Comment: Changed the answer. Now the pseudo element is only 12px wide.

Comment: God I hate myself for not figuring out that. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

While i don't know if there's a way to avoid this,
adding `box-shadow: inherit;` to the child element should fix the appearance
as it adds the same inset shadow to it.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/4fz5g/3/